# Laravel is "listening" to index.php string anywhere in the URL

Tags: php, url, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 project with routes set up as well as a custom 404 page (mostly for missing/incorrect "pages").

So basically if I open any existing route I get the correct output and every other URL is showing the 404:

- `project.com/login` - Fine, login page
- `project.com/ghdkfgl` - 404

This looks clear and seems to be working as expected. So anything I add after the slash opens either an actual existing page or a 404 page.

Unless I put a 'index.php' anywhere in the URL. In this case, Laravel is executing the request for some reason like this:

- `project.com/jhdfkds/index.php/login` - Opens the login page (the CSS and other resources are gone because of the paths but that's clear).
- `project.com/kfhjdsg/index.php/fkdhsg` - Opens a 404 (but the CSS and other resources are not loaded too).

I'm sure both of these should open the 404 since there's no such routes in my project.

I also checked for the same behavior on the Laravel documentation website (I assume its built on Laravel).

- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0 - Actual URL
- http://laravel.com/aaa - A nice 404 page
- http://laravel.com/aaa/index.php/docs/5.0 - Laravel documentation page again, same as the first one

What might be causing this? How can this be solved?

Why would Laravel even consider the 'index.php' in the middle of the URL?

Does this have anything to do with the .htaccess file? (I didn't edit it though)

Comment: Are you using Apache or nginx?

Comment: actually both. I have a mamp (with apache) running on my local machine and nginx on our dev and production servers

Comment: same issue here on nginx

Comment: Yes, I first noticed it on nginx

Comment: That's a "bug" in the way symfony determines the base URL. A [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8441) has been opened already

Comment: @lukasgeiter, thank you for pointing that out. Someone opened the issue based on my "complain" in Laravel slack channel.

Comment: @MaGnetas I see. I think I've found a fix but I'm not very certain about it. Will probably make a pull request in the next days to receive some feedback. And I'll definitely keep you updated ;)

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward. Take care

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is inside the Symfony `Request` class and how it determines the base URL. Basically it assumes that if you have a request like `aaa/index.php` that your currently running script (named `index.php`) is inside the directory `aaa` takes `aaa/index.php` as base URL.
Later it will then be stripped from the actual request URI.

I fixed this unwanted behavior with a [pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/8508) that is currently under review. I will update this post as soon as it gets merged.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. I am watching the issue and saw the pull request. Hopefully the fix will be included in next Laravel update.

Comment: I guess there's no reason to wait till your fix will become part of the framework. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i was facing in laravel 3 when i was skipping public from url. then i have placed another htaccess file in public folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This didn't help me. Also it probably would not have worked on nginx.

Comment: If you are ok with your routes then you must check your root htaccess.

Comment: But this also happens in laravel documentation pages. And htaccess is only for apache servers I assume.

Comment: htaccess basically use for directory controlling after all your problem is still persist so i'm wishing some better answers :)

Comment: Yes, I believe this is a commin Laravel bug. I also wrote in Laravel slack channel. Will keep this updated in case anything new comes up. Thank you